# Programmatically change screen saver settings

Tags: macos, swift, core-foundation

I'm trying to programmatically change the configured screen saver.

If I do

```
$ defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver
{
    CleanExit = YES;
    PrefsVersion = 100;
    idleTime = 600;
    moduleDict =     {
        moduleName = XXXX;
        path = "/Users/juanjo/Library/Screen Savers/XXXX.saver";
        type = 0;
    };
    showClock = 0;
}
```

I can see that info or even update it using the write parameter.

This settings are not accesibles via NSUserDefaults but they are via CF.

I was able to do this by code

```
var moduleDict = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue("moduleDict", "com.apple.screensaver") as CFDictionary
```

but when I try to get one value from that "dict" the program crash in this line:

```
var saverName = CFDictionaryGetValue(moduleDict, "moduleName")
```

saying `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)`.

So, do you know how can I read this values and write back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in Cocoa-Dev list, I was able to do it this way.

Reading:

```
var moduleDict = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue("moduleDict", "com.apple.screensaver") as NSDictionary
var saverName = moduleDict["moduleName"] as String!
```

Writing:

```
var moduleDict = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue("moduleDict", "com.apple.screensaver") as NSDictionary
var mutable = moduleDict.mutableCopy() as NSMutableDictionary
mutable["moduleName"] = "MyScreenSaver"
mutable["path"] = mySaverPath
CFPreferencesSetValue("moduleDict", mutable as CFPropertyList, "com.apple.screensaver", kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesCurrentHost)
CFPreferencesAppSynchronize("com.apple.screensaver")
```

Comment: As an inexperienced developer, especially in the macOS space, it is unclear how this is useful. Could you add some context around this? I got here because I suspect there's a way to change the screensaver's slide duration, and I was able to see some screensaver properties when I enter `defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver`. But I'm getting message `zsh: number expected` when I enter both `var moduleDict = CFPreferencesCopyAppValue("moduleDict", "com.apple.screensaver") as NSDictionary` or `... as NSDictionary`. (I'm on Mac M1 with macOS Monterey 12.6.1, Terminal 2.12.7 (445))